# Custom Identity User MVC 5 generates two user tables

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to customize my IdentityUser to generate a primary key as integer and change the table names.
The thing is: the primary key is generated correctly and all standard tables are created correctly by Migration with the new names, except by the User one. When I apply the Add-Migration Comand it returns me two "user tables".

Here is my code.

My custom Identity classes

```
public class User : IdentityUser<int, CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim>
{
}
public class CustomUserRole : IdentityUserRole<int> { }
public class CustomUserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<int> { }
public class CustomUserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<int> { }

public class CustomRole : IdentityRole<int, CustomUserRole>
{
    public CustomRole() { }
    public CustomRole(string name) { Name = name; }
}
```

My ApplicationDbContext

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, CustomRole, int, CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext() : base("CONNSTRING") { }


    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("Users", "dbo");
        modelBuilder.Entity<CustomRole>().ToTable("Role","dbo");
        modelBuilder.Entity<CustomUserRole>().ToTable("UserRole", "dbo");
        modelBuilder.Entity<CustomUserLogin>().ToTable("UserLogin", "dbo");
        modelBuilder.Entity<CustomUserClaim>().ToTable("UserClaims", "dbo");


    }
}
```

And the script generated by EF, which you can see generates me two "User tables" : the standard one "AspNetUsers" and my custom one "Users".

```
 public partial class teste : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            CreateTable(
                "dbo.Role",
                c => new
                    {
                        Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                        Name = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 256),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
                .Index(t => t.Name, unique: true, name: "RoleNameIndex");

            CreateTable(
                "dbo.UserRole",
                c => new
                    {
                        UserId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                        RoleId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.UserId, t.RoleId })
                .ForeignKey("dbo.Role", t => t.RoleId, cascadeDelete: true)
                .ForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUsers", t => t.UserId, cascadeDelete: true)
                .ForeignKey("dbo.Users", t => t.UserId, cascadeDelete: true)
                .Index(t => t.UserId)
                .Index(t => t.RoleId);

            CreateTable(
                "dbo.AspNetUsers",
                c => new
                    {
                        Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                        Email = c.String(maxLength: 256),
                        EmailConfirmed = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                        PasswordHash = c.String(),
                        SecurityStamp = c.String(),
                        PhoneNumber = c.String(),
                        PhoneNumberConfirmed = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                        TwoFactorEnabled = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                        LockoutEndDateUtc = c.DateTime(),
                        LockoutEnabled = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                        AccessFailedCount = c.Int(nullable: false),
                        UserName = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 256),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
                .Index(t => t.UserName, unique: true, name: "UserNameIndex");

            CreateTable(
                "dbo.UserClaims",
                c => new
                    {
                        Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                        UserId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                        ClaimType = c.String(),
                        ClaimValue = c.String(),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
                .ForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUsers", t => t.UserId, cascadeDelete: true)
                .ForeignKey("dbo.Users", t => t.UserId, cascadeDelete: true)
                .Index(t => t.UserId);

            CreateTable(
                "dbo.UserLogin",
                c => new
                    {
                        LoginProvider = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                        ProviderKey = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                        UserId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.LoginProvider, t.ProviderKey, t.UserId })
                .ForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUsers", t => t.UserId, cascadeDelete: true)
                .ForeignKey("dbo.Users", t => t.UserId, cascadeDelete: true)
                .Index(t => t.UserId);

            CreateTable(
                "dbo.Users",
                c => new
                    {
                        Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                        Email = c.String(),
                        EmailConfirmed = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                        PasswordHash = c.String(),
                        SecurityStamp = c.String(),
                        PhoneNumber = c.String(),
                        PhoneNumberConfirmed = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                        TwoFactorEnabled = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                        LockoutEndDateUtc = c.DateTime(),
                        LockoutEnabled = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                        AccessFailedCount = c.Int(nullable: false),
                        UserName = c.String(),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);

        }

        public override void Down()
        {
            DropForeignKey("dbo.UserRole", "UserId", "dbo.Users");
            DropForeignKey("dbo.UserLogin", "UserId", "dbo.Users");
            DropForeignKey("dbo.UserClaims", "UserId", "dbo.Users");
            DropForeignKey("dbo.UserRole", "UserId", "dbo.AspNetUsers");
            DropForeignKey("dbo.UserLogin", "UserId", "dbo.AspNetUsers");
            DropForeignKey("dbo.UserClaims", "UserId", "dbo.AspNetUsers");
            DropForeignKey("dbo.UserRole", "RoleId", "dbo.Role");
            DropIndex("dbo.UserLogin", new[] { "UserId" });
            DropIndex("dbo.UserClaims", new[] { "UserId" });
            DropIndex("dbo.AspNetUsers", "UserNameIndex");
            DropIndex("dbo.UserRole", new[] { "RoleId" });
            DropIndex("dbo.UserRole", new[] { "UserId" });
            DropIndex("dbo.Role", "RoleNameIndex");
            DropTable("dbo.Users");
            DropTable("dbo.UserLogin");
            DropTable("dbo.UserClaims");
            DropTable("dbo.AspNetUsers");
            DropTable("dbo.UserRole");
            DropTable("dbo.Role");
        }
    }
```

Additional information: 
The application uses the "AspNetUsers" table as the principal one.

Thankful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to map the IdentityUser to your new user table like this in your **OnModelCreating** method.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>()
                        .ToTable("Users", "dbo").Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("UserId");
```

Comment: I've tried this one, but didn't work, plus if I apply this solution I get the error  : 

 modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("Users", "dbo").Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("UserId");
            //modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("Users", "dbo");
            modelBuilder.Entity<CustomRole>().ToTable("Role","dbo");
            modelBuilder.Entity<CustomUserRole>().ToTable("UserRole", "dbo");
            modelBuilder.Entity<CustomUserLogin>().ToTable("UserLogin", "dbo");
            modelBuilder.Entity<CustomUserClaim>().ToTable("UserClaims", "dbo");

Comment: Repository.Migration.DbContext.IdentityUserLogin: : EntityType 'IdentityUserLogin' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
Repository.Migration.DbContext.IdentityUserRole: : EntityType 'IdentityUserRole' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
IdentityUserLogins: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserLogins' is based on type 'IdentityUserLogin' that has no keys defined.
IdentityUserRoles: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserRoles' is based on type 'IdentityUserRole' that has no keys defined.

Comment: Try to map those entities (IdentityUserRole,  IdentityUserRole ) to your custom table too.

Comment: you mean with the user id?
I can't underst why only User table are duplicating

Comment: I guess asp.net identity framework is trying to use some convention to create tables. By deault, IdentityUser is map to AspNet Users. and that table has reference to other tables.

Comment: I've found my mistake. 
I had othe classes called ApplicationUser inheriting IdentityUser, so I was converting the class User to table User and the ApplicationUser class was converting to AspNetUser table!